# Heavy-duty time-series charts

Tags: charts

I have a bunch of custom log files where each line has a timestamp, and some data points. I actually began writing my own macOS program to import and visualize these logs, but the sheer number of data points makes any charting package I try basically throw up. Each log file has tens of thousands of lines/datapoints (sometimes even hundreds of thousands, actually).

So, what could anyone recommend to visualize this data? I'm looking for mostly line/scatter charts, and don't have an issue transforming the data into some other form, as I already have a parser written.

It would be a bonus if the generated charts were interactive, so I could zoom around them etc., rather than just a static image, for example.

Answer (score 6):

[ZingChart](https://www.zingchart.com/) is a JavaScript charting library that supports big data sets, time-series formatting, and zooming/interactivity. You can see data comparisons here:

https://www.zingchart.com/demos/zingchart-vs/

[Line charts](https://www.zingchart.com/docs/chart-types/line-charts/) and [scatter plots](https://www.zingchart.com/docs/chart-types/scatter-plots/) are just a few of the chart types we offer. For information on how to convert Unix timestamps into readable dates, see [our section on time-series formatting (scales, tooltips, value boxes, crosshairs)](https://www.zingchart.com/docs/basic-elements/zingchart-tokens/#time-series-tokens) and [our section on time-series scales](https://www.zingchart.com/docs/basic-elements/configure-chart-scales/#scale-types-time-series-scale).

As for chart interactivity, we support [chart zooming, scrolling, and preview](https://www.zingchart.com/docs/interactive-charts/chart-zoom-pan-scroll/). (If you want the chart zoomed in to specified scale values at chart render, make sure to use the `zoomToValues` array in your scale object(s).) We also support [interactive crosshairs](https://www.zingchart.com/docs/interactive-charts/crosshairs/), which you may be interested in if you're creating a lot of time-series line and scatter charts.

Disclosure: I'm a member of the ZingChart team, happy to answer any questions about our charting library.

Answer (score 2):

[Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) + [MatPlotLib](http://matplotlib.org/) to the rescue:

- Handles big data *up to the size to require HDF5 storage*
- Interactive Charts with zoom, pan, print, save, etc.
- Free, Gratis & Open Source
- Cross Platform

Some examples [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html).

For more interactivity you can also use [bokeh](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/) which can also run in a [Jupyter](http://jupyter.org/about.html) Notebook, [examples](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/bokeh/bokeh-notebooks/blob/master/tutorial/00%20-%20intro.ipynb) & you might find it worth looking at [HoloViews](http://holoviews.org/) which lets you annotate your data and let it plot itself - there is a good example using several months worth of Earthquake data [here](http://examples.holoviews.org/Earthquake_Visualization.html).

Comment: Pandas is awesome!